# How to dynamically change an element's css class with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using angular to write a web application. I have a topbar with some links, and I would like to apply a css class to the link when it is clicked and to remove this class from the rest of the links.

For that I'm using the following code:

```
<div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
         <li ><a href="#/home" ng-click="clickedHeaderLink(this)">Home</a></li>
         <li ><a href="#/register" ng-click="clickedHeaderLink(this)">Sign in</a></li>
         <li ><a ng-controller="LoginController"  ng-click="clickedHeaderLink(this);open('sm')" >Login</a></li>
         <li ><a  href="#/contact" ng-click="clickedHeaderLink(this)">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">Arena Club</h3>
</div>
```

And then my controller:

```
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope','$http','menuFactory',function($scope,$http,menuFactory) {

var _init=function()
{
    console.log('Starting Init AppController');

    $scope.selected=false;

    console.log('Finished Init AppController');
}

$scope.clickedHeaderLink=function(element)
{
    var parentElement=element.$parent;
    angular.element(parentElement).addClass("active");
}
```

As you can see in my controller I have a function called clickedHeaderLink that is taking the element that is clicked. As I need to apply the style to the 'li' element, I'm taking the parent of the element clicked (in that case 'a'), but it is not working. Something wrong with my code. Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: strongly suggest you study some angular tutorials and get rid of the jQuery methodology

Comment: None of this code looks like jQuery code anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably take a different approach with this since it's using angular, but a quick and dirty jQuery selector would be something like:

```
$scope.clickedHeaderLink=function(element)
{
  $(element).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    //var parentElement=element.$parent;
    //angular.element(parentElement).addClass("active");
}
```

A different solution might be:

```
/*I would take a different approach and not use jQuery here. Especially since you're already using angular.*/

var menuItems = {};
['home', 'register', 'loginController', 'contact'].forEach(function(name) {
  menuItems[name] = {};
});
$scope.menuItems = menuItems;


app.controller('AppController', ['$scope','$http','menuFactory',function($scope, $http, menuFactory) {

  var _init=function() {
      console.log('Starting Init AppController');

      $scope.selected=false;

      console.log('Finished Init AppController');
  }

  $scope.clickedHeaderLink=function(element) {
    var x;
    var name = element.id;
    for (x in menuItems) {
      menuItems[x].active = (name !== x);
    }
      /*var parentElement=element.$parent;*/
      /*angular.element(parentElement).addClass("active");*/
  }

  // ...
});


// html
<div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
         <li ><a ng-class="{active: menuItems.home.active}" id="home" href="#/home" ng-click="clickedHeaderLink(this)">Home</a></li>
         <li ><a ng-class="{active: menuItems.register.active}" id="register" href="#/register" ng-click="clickedHeaderLink(this)">Sign in</a></li>
         <li ><a ng-class="{active: menuItems.loginController.active}" id="loginController" ng-controller="LoginController"  ng-click="clickedHeaderLink(this);open('sm')" >Login</a></li>
         <li ><a ng-class="{active: menuItems.contact.active}" id="contact" href="#/contact" ng-click="clickedHeaderLink(this)">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">Arena Club</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a great answer! I'm learning Angular Js so I will go definetely for the Angular Js approach that you posted here. Thanks again!